Receiving interactive shells with Fabric instead of expected output
I am new to Python and wanted to know how to best handle this situation. I am currently trying to run a series of commands on remote Linux servers. Each server has one user and a root user on them. I am currently using Fabric to automate this task, but I am getting unexpected behavior.
I have tried the following:
import from fabric import *

connect_kwargs = {'key_filename': r'C:path\to\key'}

conn = Connection('X.X.X.X', user = 'user1', connect_kwargs = connect_kwargs)
conn.run("hostname", pty=True,warn=True)

returns the proper hostname
Conversely, running
connect_kwargs = {'key_filename': r'C:path\to\key'}

conn = Connection('X.X.X.X', user = 'root_user', connect_kwargs = connect_kwargs)
conn.run("hostname", pty=True,warn=True)

returns an interactive shell waiting for user input. I have found a workaround using Responders, but it seems as if this is more of a patchwork solution as opposed to a complete one.

Like the syntax coloring feature easily reveals, there is a closing quote missing on the first line of the second example. Surely that's not what you are asking about?

Hi, no that is not what I am asking about. I just used that as a dummy value to demonstrate a small piece of code. As it stands, the profile I’m using in the actual environment has no missing quotes.

Going forward, please [edit] to fix such distractions yourself.

If you log in and run hostname as root, does it return the hostname, or prompt for interaction?

When running as root I get the prompt for interaction.

Then that's the problem, and your question is unrelated to Python or Fabric.
